# Running Java project through command line (with Maven dependencies)

Tags: java, macos, maven, terminal

I want to run my working Java project through my terminal (mac). It uses Maven to pull in required dependencies. Any help would be very much appreciated.

First I ran the commend: 
`mvn clean install`

Next:
`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`

Finally:
`cd target/
java -cp MyProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:dependency Main`

Unfortunately the following error is thrown (clearly showing the dependencies are not being used correctly):

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser
        at Main$Quote.quoteMachine(Hi.java:21)
        at Main.main(Hi.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser` ...

Comment: Does the `dependency` directory contains the expected dependencies? If so should you not use `dependency/*` ?

Comment: They are all present in my dependency folder (in the target directory)

Comment: So maven did it's job as expected and the issue is between you and the `java` executable. Did you try adding `dependency/*` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by adding this to my POM file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After this I simply ran the following commands in my terminal:

```
mvn clean install
```

And then:

```
mvn exec:java
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. Otherwise, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven#574650

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the `json-simple-.jar` in your classpath.

Comment: does the command "java -cp MyProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:dependency Main" not do that?

Comment: is it appear in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your web application deployed ?

Comment: I'm just trying to run it in my local terminal, no web application

Comment: right click on project-> build path -> configure build path -> java build path -> add external jars -> select the jar file. also add build path entry into deployment assembly.